# Can I change the exclude file list while running rsync under a cron job

Tags: cron, rsync, backup

I am using Fedora 20, MATE desktop, zshell. I have started a cronjob to run, every evening, an incremental backup using rsync, closely following the suggestions [here](http://webgnuru.com/linux/rsync_incremental.php). After the first run yesterday, which has established a full back up on an external hard drive, and looking at the result I see that I would like to omit some more files, notably `/home/Harry/.local/share/Trash` which is 3.6Gb. So please is it all right to ad this path to my existing `exclude` file?

To forestall some obvious comments. The log file produced by rsync dry run had almost 800000 lines, so not easy to look through for such items. I could consult the manual, but that is too complex to go looking for an answer to such a question.